# How to optimizely fetch MySQL data from query for charts grouped by week

Tags: php, mysql, date

My Mysql's table structure is like:

Table name : **visitor_sessions_data**

```
------------------------------
date_time           | visitor_sessions
------------------------------
2016-12-01 14:00:00 | 2
------------------------------
2016-12-01 18:50:10 | 1
------------------------------
2016-12-19 06:00:00 | 1
------------------------------
2016-12-20 16:00:00 | 1
------------------------------
2017-02-02 19:00:00 | 3
------------------------------
```

and so on...

And I want to fetch the data to display in graphs in daily, weekly and monthly order.

I can easily fetch the data to render in chart if daily data is shown.
For that I wrote:

```
SELECT date('date_time'), visitor_sessions 
FROM visitor_sessions_data 
WHERE (date('date_time')>='2016-12-01') AND (date('date_time')<='2017-02-10') 
GROUP BY date('date_time')
```

So this gives me the data count grouped by each date.

The issue I am facing in calculating the Weekly data as per my own thinking.
I am actually unable to build optimized logic for fetching the weekly data from this table.

My requirement is to provide data to chart in following manner:

```
Week 1: 3,
Week 2: 2,
Week 3: 0,
Week 4: 0,
Week 5: 0,
....
Week X: 3,
```

Please note: Here week 1 means it should start counting the first date as week 1 (which I provide in mysql), and a week starts from **Monday**

I tried using this sql but it is only grouping and showing records for weeks where data exists, and doesn't show data for weeks where **visitor_sessions** are **zero**:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(payment_added,'%X-%V'), visitor_sessions 
FROM visitor_sessions_data 
WHERE (date('date_time')>='2016-12-01') AND (date('date_time')<='2017-02-10') 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(payment_added,'%X-%V')
```

Please help.

Thanks.

I also seek your help in building query for getting grouped data for
- monthly
- quarterly
- yearly

Comment: No, but actually I am unable to think the logic for getting data grouped by quarterly also.

Comment: This is not duplicate question

Comment: It does not matter, whether you need the data by day, or week, or month, or quarter. The duplicate topic describes a generic approach and provides a rationale as to why you need that in mysql. There are variations as to how you generate the helper data, but you do need the helper data to fill the gaps left in your own data.